# Character pointer to a union storage

Tags: c, hex, byte

I am trying to trace out the value at 1st byte of the union with the help of a char pointer.I assume that the output for byte1 should be ff but instead it's ffffffff.
Correct me If I am  wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>


struct TriggerMsg
{
  uint32_t x[3];
  uint32_t y[3];
};


struct sysData
{
      union
      {
         TriggerMsg tTrigger;
         uint8_t u8Wakeup;
         uint8_t u8Reset;
      }
      u;
};

int main()
{  
   sysData sys;

   for(int i =0 ; i<3 ; i++)
   {
     sys.u.tTrigger.x[i] = 0;
     sys.u.tTrigger.y[i]= 0;
   }

   sys.u.u8Wakeup = 0xffffffff;
   //sys.u.tTrigger = { 0 };


   char *c = (char *)&(sys.u) ;

   printf("u.tTrigger.x = %x \nu.tTrigger.y = %x \nu.u8Wakeup = %d \n\n" , \
           sys.u.tTrigger.x[0], sys.u.tTrigger.y[0], sys.u.u8Wakeup);

   for(int i=0; i<24;i++) 
   printf("Byte%d = %x \n", i, c[i]) ;


   return 0;
}


Output:

u.tTrigger.x = ff
u.tTrigger.y = 0
u.u8Wakeup = 255

Byte0 = ffffffff
Byte1 = 0
Byte2 = 0
Byte3 = 0
Byte4 = 0
Byte5 = 0
Byte6 = 0
Byte7 = 0
Byte8 = 0
Byte9 = 0
Byte10 = 0
Byte11 = 0
Byte12 = 0
Byte13 = 0
Byte14 = 0
Byte15 = 0
Byte16 = 0
Byte17 = 0
Byte18 = 0
Byte19 = 0
Byte20 = 0
Byte21 = 0
Byte22 = 0
Byte23 = 0
```

I am trying to trace out the value at 1st byte of the union with the help of a char pointer.I assume that the output for byte1 should be ff but instead it's ffffffff.
Correct me If I am  wrong.

Comment: `iostream` header is C++, how are you compiling this?

Comment: `c[i]` gets sign extended as it is promoted to int type before printing

Comment: `sys.u.u8Wakeup = 0xffffffff`????? Trying to store a 32-bit value in an 8-bit variable???

Comment: This unrelated to the problem, but your code is unnecessarily including the C++ header `iostream`. You are also assuming automatic C++ `typedef`s for `struct`s.

Comment: @barak: We were just trying out different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%x` format prints `unsigned int`s, but your `char` is signed. It is promoted to a `signed int` when passed to `printf`. This leads to the unexpected output when the negative value in the signed integer is shown as though it were unsigned.

Change the `char` to `unsigned char` to fix this:

```
unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)&(sys.u);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably wanted is not char but unsigned char.
The first bit in a signed char indicates the sign, so there are only 7 bit left for the actual value. This results in interpreting 0xff as decimal -1 which is printed as hexadecimal 0xffffffff.
With an unsigned char everything is fine.

Comment: agreed.But As Arkku pointed out, this ahs got to do with the implicit conversion of types for printf